# Nesting a recursive function inside another

Tags: r, recursion

I haven't dabbled much with recursive functions, but successfully coded `f()` which does the job of outputting a vector (N = 3 in this case) of probabilities.

```
# Data
ps <- structure(c(0.68, 0.255, 0, 0.17, 0.595, 0, 0.15, 0.15, 1), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
po <- structure(c(0.7, 0, 0, 0.3, 1, 1), .Dim = 3:2)
pp <- c(1,0,0)
y <- c(1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2)
```

```
# Recursive function
f <- function(o,pp,q = 1,si = 1:(nrow(ps)){
  if(q == length(si)) return(0)
  else{
    return(ps[q,si]*po[si,o]*pp[q] + f(o = o,pp = pp,q+1,si = si))
  }
}

> f(y[2],pp)
[1] 0.476 0.000 0.000
> f(y[3],pp)
[1] 0.204 0.170 0.150
```

Now, I need the output of `f(o = y[2],pp = pp)` as the argument for `pp` in `f(o = y[3],pp = .)`. So on and so forth until `o` is exhausted. Intuitively it seems recursion is the answer once again, but I'm unable to grok a solution.

I can arrive at the correct answer a few ways. Below is a `for` loop. This answer seems wasteful as I would be initializing a matrix every time I call the function as well as storing unneeded values. I suppose another solution would be to keep overwriting `pp` in a loop. Another way would be to nest `f()` or pipe them together, but this seems redundant and not very flexible. Is there a more elegant solution?

Desired output:

```
g <- function(pp,obs){
  b <- matrix(0,3,8)
  b[,1] <- pp
  for(i in 2:8){
    b[,i] <- f(o = obs[i],pp = b[,i-1])
  }
  log(sum(b[,8]))
}

> g(pp = pp,obs = y)
[1] -6.439479
```

P.S. I understand there are packages available that will do what I'm trying to do (Hidden Markov Model - Forward Algorithm). I'm just trying to understand what's happening under the hood and get a better handle on recursive programming. I appreciate any help from the community. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the matrix, you can just keep replacing the `pp` values

```
g <- function(pp, obs) {
  for ( i in 2:8) {
    pp <- f(obs[i], pp)
  }
  log(sum(pp))
}
g(pp, y)
# [1] -6.439479
```

Comment: I realized this loop was overengineered and suggested this solution in my lengthy text. I guess I was hoping to find a solution using recursion. Maybe I'm getting too fancy.